# How to calculate Day(s) and Hour(s) remaining in swift between two dates?

Tags: swift, date

I have output `2019-11-23` and today's date `2019-11-4`. How do I calculate the number of days remaining for these two dates? the output should be

> 19d5h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DateFormatter` and `DateComponents` to get this working.

Get the `Date` instances from `String` using `DateFormatter` and then get `day` and `hour` components using `DateComponents`, i.e.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

if let d1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-11-23"), let d2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-11-4") {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour], from: d2, to: d1)
    print(components.day, components.hour)
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `hour` component in the output since it will always be 0.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Right. That's just if OP adds the hour to dates as well. Otherwise there won't be any requirement if hour.

Comment: You should set date formatter locale to en_US_POSIX when using a fixed date format